# Unable to add window title in SystemDialogInput

Tags: dialog-window

There appears to be an option called WindowTitle for the SystemDialogInput, but it does not seem to do anything for me:

```
SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", WindowTitle -> "Please locate a file"]
```

[image]

I would have thought it would place the requested text "Please locate a file" somewhere on the dialog window. Is this an OS or version dependent phenomenon? (I'm on Mac OS 10.14.2 and Mathematica 11.3.0).

Comment: Yes, works well on Windows.

Comment: Can anyone with Mac OS confirm whether this happens? The alternative is that it is something idiosyncratic to my installation. Thanks!

Comment: works fine on Mac. I use this all the time

Comment: I can confirm I get no window title on any M version I try this on, using Mac OS 10.14.1.

Answer (score 3):

With V11.3 on macOS 10.13, you can't set the window title with `SystemDialogOutput`. I reported this problem to Wolfram tech support in May of last year and received the following answer:

> I was able to reproduce the regression you describe, and I believe this is a result of changes Apple made in macOS 10.13. I have filed a report with our developers asking that this be something we investigate and look to address.